# Creating a simple Java Rule Engine

Tags: java, rule-engine

We are trying to build a generic Alert Registration Service for consumers. Here is the problem we are trying to solve :

1. An alert can have 'N' templates registered.Each template would be picked up based on a rule match
2. The rule is going to be something like this :

   {"rule1":{"fieldName":"field1","operator":">","value":"100"}

   FieldName could be something like - accountBal, status etc. Operator could be arithmetic operators like ("+","-","/","*") or logical operations like (&&, == , ||)
   We are planning to define a /registration service and an /execute service.

Let us take a rule say :
rule1 = field1 > 100 --> choose Template 1
rule2 = field1 >=100 && field2 <150 - Choose Template 2

Basically I am envisioning it like this :

```
abstract class Rule
{
    private String field;
    private Operator symbol;
    private String fieldValue

}
```

A Rule --> can resolve to N Templates and the system should send me the list of templates back.

I did start looking at the Interpreter pattern and the Rule pattern, but I have not found I am looking at.

Basically I need a way to configure rules (will be sent as json) from service API and stored in DB. At runTime , based on the applicationId, bunch of rules will be fired and will return `List<Template>`

Any help would be appreciated

I was planning to use a custom Rule Engine with StandardEvaluationContext, but an example would help me get going.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Yes. I am trying to see how I can use Spring EL StandardEvaluationContext in conjuction with a RuleRegistry to register rules and execute at runtime.

Comment: A Java Scripting API, say with JavaScript would do fine, where "rule" then is a script (or function) evaluating to a boolean result. Advantage: numeric types. Alternatively since Java 9: REPL functionality, also programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I has used Apache Velocity to create a rule engine.
 Velocity provides ‘eval’ function which is able to evaluate boolean expressions.